# Managed Package "This extension depends on the package you are trying to uninstall. force-app"

Tags: managed-package

I'm attempting to uninstall a managed package and I'm getting this error. I'm tearing my hair out trying to figure it out. Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you have multiple packages installed in your org? Is one of them called "force-app"? The message suggests you have a package which depends upon the package you're attempting to uninstall.

Comment: There is no package called 'force-app' that I can see.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your Installed Packages screen? You're not in a packaging org, are you?

Answer (score 0):

Had something similar to this and I raised a case. Check [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000334997&type=1&mode=1) link.
It is also weird because the **force-app** is a folder on the DX that contains all files related to a project, org, etc ...

[image]